# How to query the latest item in a feed table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

There is a table called `client_application` with data something like this;

```
Id   user_id   name      creationDate
---------------------------------------
1    5         name1     date
2    4         name2     date
3    98        name3     date
```

And also a table called `application_status` which holds the status feed of application(`application_id` is foreign key);

```
Id   aplication_id   status            other_columns      creationDate
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1    1       APPLICATION_SUMITTED      data               date
2    2       APPLICATION_SUMITTED      data               date
3    1       APPLICATION_RECEVIED      data               date
4    1       BANK_APPROVED             data               date
5    3       APPLICATION_SUMITTED      data               date
6    2       APPLICATION_RECEVIED      data               date
```

I want to query the application by their status. For example get the newest submitted applications? Or get the applications which the bank approved.

How can I implement such an SQL query?

I have tried thi;

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM application_status ORDER BY creationDate DESC) t1
LEFT JOIN client_application on client_application.id = t1.application_id
GROUP BY t1.application_id;
```

Which is fine, I can get the applications with their latest status but when I try to put a where clause in it;

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM application_status ORDER BY creationDate DESC) t1
LEFT JOIN client_application on client_application.id = t1.application_id
where t1.status = 'APPLICATION_SUBMITTED'
GROUP BY t1.application_id;
```

It returns all `application_status` has `APPLICATION_SUBMITTED` status column..
It returns `application_id` 1 item ( check the table above) but as you can see, application with the id number 1 has `APPLICATION_RECEIVED` status as latest status item.. So I would not expect this one in result set.

Maybe my approach is totally wrong. I'm open for any solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to improve the design of your database by creating a new table 'Status' for example :

```
Id   Label
1    APPLICATION_SUBMITTED
2    APPLICATION_RECEIVED
3    BANK_APPROVED
```

You have to give the labels a logical order, and you refer to this table in your status or main table.

It will be easier to retrieve the status of an application ( where Status.Id < 3 to select all non-approved applications, or where Status.Id > 1 to select all application that are at least received ).

It is also better for maintenance purpose. This kind of logic applies in a lot of cases, and you should consider to spend a bit more time to design your data models, so you won't spend more time resolving this kind of issue your are facing now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you want group by there but maybe you just want

```
select apps.*, ca.*
from application_status apps
 left join client_application ca on ca.id = apps.application_id
WHERE apps.status = 'APPLICATION_SUBMITTED'
  AND not exists ( select 1 
                   from application_status 
                   where application_id = apps.application_id 
                     and creationdate > apps.creationdate 
                  )
ORDER BY apps.creation_date DESC, apps.application_id
```

EDIT [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3f95/4)

Comment: nope the problem with this solution it returns the application which has APPLICATION_RECEIVED status already.

Comment: @tylerdurden are you sure ? I've changed this query many times so please check it again.

Comment: last one is ok but I'm going with Thomas's answer it's more simple and elegant way i think. Thanks man anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM application_status ORDER BY creationDate DESC) AS A GROUP BY application_id) AS t1
LEFT JOIN client_application ON client_application.id = t1.application_id
WHERE t1.status = 'APPLICATION_SUBMITTED'
```

Comment: this one is ok but I'm going with Thomas's answer it's more simple and elegant way i think. Thanks man anyway.